# Using Razor without Visual Studio? System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper vs. System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I am trying to create a website using some of the Razor functionality, but without using Visual Studio. The main reason for this is that I'm currently mainly working from a Mac, and I'd like to use Coda for editing the pages.

I don't need a programmable website, in the sense of database access, that sort of thing, but I'd like to use RenderPartial so that I can split up the pages and implement some common functionality, like menus and so on.

So, I tried the following:

1. I created a new site under IIS7
2. I dropped in a .cshtml file with this code: `@DateTime.Now`
3. I opened it through Chrome

This displayed the current date and time, so clearly the razor engine executes.

Then I tried the following code:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("menu.cshtml")
```

and I get this error message:

> c:\inetpub\drip\dev2\index.cshtml(1,12): error CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' and no extension method 'RenderPartial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Clearly, the identifier `Html` refers to a different class than I expected.

So, is there a tutorial on how to do this? Is it at all possible?

This code:

```
@Html.GetType().FullName
```

Outputs this:

> System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper

I don't need to use `Html` as the identifier, if I can create my own variable referring to the right object/type/class instance, that'd be more than enough for me.

Comment: Do you have all the necessary Web.config etc stuff for an ASP.NET Web Pages site?

Comment: I tried that, does not seem to make any difference, at least not regarding this particular exception.

Comment: But is it MVC 3 or Web Pages?

Comment: I added a Web.config file from a ASP.NET MVC 3 project, basic unedited Web.config file from such a project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Clearly, the identifier Html refers to a different class than I expected.

Yes, it refers to [System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) which is used by WebPages. In ASP.NET MVC it is the [System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) class.

The base class of your template is the [WebPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) class whereas in ASP.NET MVC it is the [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) class.

But since you are using WebPages you could rely only on the methods defined by it. For example if you wanted to include a partial you could do the following:

`~/_SiteLayout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

`~/Default.cshtml`:

```
@{  
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Welcome to my Web Site!";
}
<div>Welcome</div>

@RenderPage("Menu.cshtml")
```

`~/Menu.cshtml`:

```
@{  
    Layout = null;
}
<div>Some menu</div>
```

`web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You may take a look at the [WebPages documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-pages). There are lots of tutorials out there.

Comment: This worked nicely. I'm sure "switching" Html over to the MVC type would work as well, but as I said, I want to use razor engine, and basically "include" other files, and this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to reference `System.Web.Mvc.Html` in your web.config to be able to use extension methods from [RenderPartialExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492211.aspx)

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
   <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
     </namespaces>
   </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put that? I feel like such a beginner when it comes to web.config, I tried putting it alongside `<system.web>`, but that give me an error, "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Comment: I edited the web.config, cleaned it up by removing a lot of things not needed (I found a different question here on SO), and now I get this error: "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page_index_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.". The code in my .cshtml file is still only `@Html.GetType().FullName`

Comment: Have you tried using a default generated web.config for a ASP.NET MVC3 project? Config section for razor which you added also needs to be registered. I pasted one [here](http://pastebin.com/K7gv5saM) if you have no way to get one atm.